# Why am I obtaining these type error in my Anuglar project?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am working on an Angular project following a Udemy course and I am finding some problem related to the type (I suppose that the course instructor is using an old version of Angular and that I have to adapt his code in some way). Following my situation:

First of all I have this model class named **Exercise**:

```
export interface Exercise {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    duration: number;
    calories: number;
    date?: Date;
    state?: 'completed' | 'cancelled' | null;
}
```

Then I have this service class:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Exercise } from "./exercise.model";

export class TrainingService {

    exerciseChanged: Subject<Exercise | null> = new Subject<Exercise | null>();
    
    private availableExercise: Exercise[] = [
        { id: 'crunches', name: 'Crunches', duration: 30, calories: 8 },
        { id: 'touch-toes', name: 'Touch Toes', duration: 180, calories: 15 },
        { id: 'side-lunges', name: 'Side Lunges', duration: 120, calories: 18 },
        { id: 'burpees', name: 'Burpees', duration: 60, calories: 8 }
    ];

    private runningExercise: Exercise | undefined | null;

    private exercises: Exercise[]  = [];

    getAvailableExercises(): Exercise[] {
        return this.availableExercise.slice();
    }

    startExercise(selectedId: string) {
        this.runningExercise  = this.availableExercise.find(ex => ex.id === selectedId) as Exercise;
        this.exerciseChanged.next({ ...this.runningExercise});

    }

    completeExercise() {
        this.exercises.push({ 
                                ...this.runningExercise as Exercise, 
                                date: new Date(), 
                                state: 'completed' 
                            });
        this.runningExercise = null;
        this.exerciseChanged.next(null);

    }

    cancelExercise(progress: number) {
        this.exercises.push({ 
            ...this.runningExercise as Exercise, 
            duration: this.runningExercise.duration,
            calories: 
            date: new Date(), 
            state: 'cancelled' 
        });
        this.runningExercise = null;
        this.exerciseChanged.next(null);

    }

    getRunningExercise() {
        return { ...this.runningExercise } as Exercise
    }
}
```

In particular I am finding problem in this method code:

```
cancelExercise(progress: number) {
    this.exercises.push({ 
        ...this.runningExercise as Exercise, 
        duration: this.runningExercise.duration,
        calories: 
        date: new Date(), 
        state: 'cancelled' 
    });
    this.runningExercise = null;
    this.exerciseChanged.next(null);

}
```

My types problem are on these lines related to the new **Exercise** object that I am pushing into my **exercises** array:

```
duration: this.runningExercise.duration,
```

giving me this error into my console:

```
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2533)
```

and

```
    date: new Date(),
```

giving me this error into my console:

```
Error: src/app/training/training.service.ts:46:13 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'date'. Did you mean 'Date'?

46             date: new Date(),
           ~~~~
```

The first one seems to be related to the fact that I am trying to access to a value of an object that can be undefined or null (this.runningExercise).

The second one I really not getting it.

How can I try to solve these types error?

Comment: Is TrainingService a service or a component?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

From:

```js
private runningExercise: Exercise | undefined | null
```

The compiler warns you that the variable is possibly `null`. While `duration` is a `number` type, the type will **fail** when `runningExercise` is `null` or `undefined`.

Make sure that you had handled `runningExercise` when it is `null` or `undefined` before assigning the value to `duration`. For the below case, I use `?.` optional chaining and `??` nullish coalescing operator to deal with.

**Issue 2**

It is due to the previous line `calories:`, you didn't assign the value and missing the `,` at behind.

```js
this.exercises.push({ 
    ...this.runningExercise as Exercise, 
    duration: this.runningExercise?.duration ?? 0,
    calories: 1, // Assign the value and end with comma ',' 
    date: new Date(), 
    state: 'cancelled' 
});
```